# Evernote on Ubuntu/Wine black background buttons

Tags: ubuntu, wine, evernote

I installed Evernote 3.1 on Ubuntu 9.1 via Wine 1.2-rc4 and would like to know if there's a way to fix the button's images - they are displayed inside a black box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [this Bug-Report from Wine](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201).